# Bind event to multiple objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to attach the same behavior to several different elements and haven't been able to figure out how.

Given the below snippet of code, if you were to click on the button the events fire for both buttons simultaneously. I'm wondering if it's possible to trigger the event for only the button that was clicked without resorting to creating methods for `button1` and `showInside1`, etc.

```js
var App = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
        showInside: false
    }
  },
  methods:{
    show: function () {
        this.showInside = true 
    },
    hide: function () { 
        console.log('hide')
        this.showInside = false
    }
  },
  events: {
    closeEvent: function () {
      console.log('close event called')
      this.hide()
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click.stop="show">1 Click me</button>
  <div v-if="showInside">
    <p>This is box 1</p>  
    <button @click="hide">Close</button>
  </div>


  <button @click.stop="show">2 Click me</button>
  <div v-if="showInside">
    <p>This is box 2</p>  
    <button @click="hide">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider moving the common code to a [component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) with [slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html) to reduce the repetitive code and to isolate the data properties:

```js
Vue.component('my-section', {
  template: `
    <div class="my-section">
      <button @click.stop="showInside = true">Click me</button>
      <div v-if="showInside">
        <slot></slot>
        <button @click="showInside = false">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>`,
  data() {
    return {
        showInside: false
    }
  },
  methods:{
    show: function () {
        this.showInside = true 
    },
    hide: function () { 
        console.log('hide')
        this.showInside = false
    }
  },
  events: {
    closeEvent: function () {
      console.log('close event called')
      this.hide()
    }
  }
})

var App = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
})
```

```css
.my-section {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-section>
    <p>This is box 1</p>
  </my-section>
  <my-section>
    <p>This is box 2</p>
  </my-section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

While `showInside` is Boolean it's impossible. You should keep each box's state:

```
data() {
    return {
        show: {
          panel1: false,
          panel2: false,
        }
    }
  },
```

then:

```
<div id="app">
  <button @click.stop="show.panel1 = true">1 Click me</button>
  <div v-if="show.panel1">
    <p>This is box 1</p>  
    <button @click="show.panel1 = false">Close</button>
  </div>


  <button @click.stop="show.panel2 = true">2 Click me</button>
  <div v-if="show.panel2">
    <p>This is box 2</p>  
    <button @click="show.panel2 = false">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course  you can use arrays and `v-for` for dynamic cases